# Hausdorff Lindelöf Space is Regular?

Tags: general-topology

I think we can use same argument for saying regular Lindelöf space is normal to prove Hausdorff Lindelöf space is regular. But, I didn't heard about this proposition. What is the problem of using same argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument does not go through. A quite complicated construction called the “irrational-slope topology” is given by [Steen and Seebach (1978)](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-6290-9) with the following properties:

- Hausdorff; but
- *not* regular; yet
- second-countable (and hence Lindelöf).

I think the problem is as follows. In proving that every Lindelöf regular space is normal, you first take two disjoint closed sets, say $A$ and $B$, and separate each $a\in A$ from $B$ (using regularity) by an open neighborhood of $a$ whose closure does not cut into $B$ and *vice versa*.

But!

If the space is only Hausdorff and you're trying to prove regularity along the same lines (*i.e.*, show that if $a\notin B$ and $B$ is closed, then $a$ and $B$ can be separated by open neighborhoods), then the closure of the analogous open neighborhood of $a$ that separates it from some $b\in B$ (using the Hausdorff property) may actually cut into $B$ at some other point $b'\in B$! That's why an analogous argument breaks down.